# Project Euler #211: Divisor Square Sum

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, c++14, factors

I started doing hackerrank problems only recently and here's my attempt to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler211/problem).

Basically, you're given two integers `N` and `K`, so you need to find the sum of all `1 <= n <= N` such that the sum is at most `K` away from a perfect square.

For example, for `N = 65` and `K = 0`, we calculate the sum of squares of factors for all numbers from `1` to `65`, i.e. `1, 5, 10, ...` and see which of these sums is a perfect square (or more precisely `0` away from a perfect square). For `65`, that happens to be `1` and `42`, so the answer would be `43`.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Lookup table
unordered_map<uint_fast16_t, uint_fast16_t> fac_sq_diff;

auto sum_fac_sq(uint_fast16_t n) {
    uint_fast16_t sum = 0;
    // Calculate factors in pairs,
    // eg. 20 => (1, 20), (2, 10), (4, 5)
    auto sqrtn = sqrt(n);
    for (auto i = 1; i <= sqrtn; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            sum += (i * i);
            auto j = n / i;
            if (i != j) {
                sum += (j * j);
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


uint_fast32_t solve(uint_fast16_t n, uint_fast16_t k) {
    uint_fast32_t result = 0;
    int_fast32_t diff = 0;
    for (uint_fast16_t j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
        auto idiff = fac_sq_diff.find(j);
        if (idiff == fac_sq_diff.end()) {
            auto sum = sum_fac_sq(j);
            // Closest perfect square:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054909
            auto sqrtsum = static_cast<uint_fast16_t>(sqrt(static_cast<float>(sum)) + .5f);
            diff = sum - (sqrtsum * sqrtsum);
            diff = abs(diff);
            idiff = fac_sq_diff.emplace(j, diff).first;
        }

        if (idiff->second <= k) {
            result += j;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // Expected input:
    // 11
    // 65 0
    // 269 1
    // 312 2
    // 745 3
    // 1457 4
    uint_fast16_t q = 1;
    cin >> q;

    // Find max N and reserve lookup table mem
    vector<pair<uint_fast16_t, uint_fast16_t>> NK;
    uint_fast16_t max_N = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < q; ++i) {
        uint_fast16_t N = 0, K = 0;
        cin >> N >> K;
        NK.emplace_back(N, K);
        max_N = max(N, max_N);
    }
    fac_sq_diff.reserve(max_N);

    for (auto &nk: NK) {
        cout << solve(nk.first, nk.second) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No matter what I try, I am not able to get past the first test (in terms of speed). :(

I also tried the geometric summation formula to calculate the sum of factors squared, but my implementation turned out to be slower than this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always, before tackling the Project Euler problems, do your math homework. Few hints:

- Do not brute force. \$\sigma_2(n)\$ is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function). That allows it to be computed in a much more efficient way.
- Do not throw away your work. \$\sigma_2(n)\$ does not depend on \$k\$. Tabulate it once toward the maximal possible \$N\$, or extend it as \$N\$ grows.

Besides that, the constraints say \$1 < N < 6\cdot 10^6, 0 < K < 10^6\$. `uint_16` is surely insufficient.

Comment: +1 especially for reviewing the code and algorithm without revealing a complete solution and leaving the fun of discovery intact.

Comment: Very helpful information, particularly regarding the multiplicative function. I think I'm back on track, thanks to you.